# Show that $|\pi^{(i e)}| = 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I really don't know how to go about this. I have tried messing around with the Euler identity but I just can't seem to manipulate it enough.

$$|\pi^{(i e)}| = 1$$

Comment: Calculate $|e^{x+iy}|$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\pi^{ie} = \left(e^{\ln\pi}\right)^{ie} = e^{ie\ln\pi}$, and $ie\ln\pi$ is pure imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

In general, complex exponentiation is defined as $w^z = e^{z\log(w)}$ for any $w, z \in \mathbb{C}$ (wherein this takes infinitely many values unless an appropriate branch cut for the logarithm is selected).  At any rate, $\pi^{ie} = e^{ie\log(\pi)} = e^{i\log(\pi^e)}$.

Now you can finish up by converting to rectangular coordinates via the Euler identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use, as Kaj Hansen wrote, $$\pi^{ie} = e^{ie\log(\pi)} $$ and Euler identity, you have $$\pi^{ie} =\cos (e \log (\pi ))+i \sin (e \log (\pi ))$$

Comment: I see how you guys got there, know I have something of the form z = a + i*b so |z| = z*zbar and this results in 1? Is this correct?